# Manifest does not work in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, registry, manifest, registrykey

I'm trying to allow my program to write to the HKLM Keys. In order to achieve that I tried to create a manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

But even with this file I'm still getting an exception:

```
"System.UnauthorizedAccessException" in mscorlib.dll 
Cannot write to the registry key.
```

I'm using VS2015. I click create new element then pick Manifest file. Set the name to MyProgram.exe.manifest. Then in Project properties I select the proper manifest. And finally I'm changing execution level in Manifest file to requireAdministrator and rebuild the program.

But when I'm executing the MyProgram.exe it never shows that UAC window and when I try to write to HKLM in throws an exception. So I suspect the manifest is not working properly.

Please advise.
Thank you!!

Comment: "Then in Project properties I select the proper manifest".  That doesn't make any sense so whatever you do there, just don't do it.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you :/

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

- using administrator run program.
- No permission to set permissions.

Comment: I've tried to run it as an Administrator. Does not help.

Comment: You can change other computer and then run MyProgram.exe.If it can run success,you can check your computer configurations.